# I need to insert my json file into the sqlite database

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have to insert my json file into the sqlite database, I am not very familiar with this.

This is my json file:

```
{
    "1": [{
        "id": "title1",
        "title": "icon1",
        "icon": "1",
        "file": "1"
    }],
    "2": [{
        "id": "title2",
        "title": "icon2",
        "icon": "1",
        "file": "2"
    }]
}
```

This is my script json reader:

```
    $.getJSON('json/it-de.json',function(data) {
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
            alert("5");
            $.each(data, function(i, dat) {
var id = idl,id;
var title = idl,title;
var icon = idl,icon;
var file = idl,file;

alert(test);
tx.executeSql('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO MYTABLE (id,title,icon,file) VALUES("'+id+'", "'+title+'", "'+icon+'", "'+file+'")');
            });
            alert("completed");
        }, function() { 
});
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to be more specific

I assume that you get an error when you execute the script. It would be helpfull if you write it here. In other case, describe what happens when you execute it.

Best regards